# Raspberry Pi Zero 1.3 Audio pins

Tags: usb-power, pi-zero, retropie, composite-video

So I saw this awesome project Element 14 did with the Pi here

https://www.element14.com/community/docs/DOC-79282/l/raspberry-pi-zero-retro-gaming-system

I have a Pi Zero 1.3 and I want to do this project. My question is  Where are the audio points on the board to accomplish this on Zer0 1.3? Also is it possible to solder a USB hub and use all the ports?

Comment: One of the last pictures there shows the hub attached via the connector, not soldered in.  There's some comment to the effect that they hacked the hub to power the zero (notice it has an extra cable) with too but depending on the hub that's not necessary -- you can power the pi through either microUSB jack, i.e., if you use the data one and the hub provides a powered master line, that's all you need.

Answer (score 1):

So you could just get an HDMI TV and output your audio over that, but that's boring so I'll skip it.

You could (and for audio quality purposes perhaps should) use USB audio instead of PWM if you can (the PWM has all kinds of noise, so audiophile-quality sound is nigh impossible...).

Nope?  Really want to use PWM?  OK then.

I did a project using PWM on a Zero a while back (and am working on another) and basically it boils down to:

1. [Remap the PWM pins to some on the header](https://learn.adafruit.com/adding-basic-audio-ouput-to-raspberry-pi-zero/pi-zero-pwm-audio)
2. [Hook the pins up to a proper filter](http://hackaday.com/2015/12/05/swapping-gpio-pins-on-the-pi-zero-for-audio/).  Note that you probably don't need the diodes, since you'll likely:
3. [Plug the output straight into an audio amp and speakers](http://www.instructables.com/id/LM386-Audio-Amplifier/) on a permanent basis.

And of course if you're going old-skool, you'll be using [RCA composite video](https://learn.adafruit.com/introducing-the-raspberry-pi-zero/video-outputs), right?

Finally, programming this thing (especially if you're being intentionally wonky with the video) is much easier if you use an FTDI cable or (better yet) connect over [SSH using a USB cable to your PC](https://learn.adafruit.com/turning-your-raspberry-pi-zero-into-a-usb-gadget/ethernet-gadget).

I friggin' love this little board!  All the best luck to you, sir!